# Where are the netns config files?

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I can't find the network namespace config files. Do I have to reconfigure the `ip netns` interfaces after every reboot?

https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html

Comment: Why would you expect there to be any? And what Linux distribution is this?

Comment: Normally, when I configure an IP address for an interface, I write a file using RedHat Enterprise Linux in /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-eth0 which contains the IP address and other such configuration. After reboot, the IP address is still configured. Is there a similar mechanism for `netns` namespaces? Do I have to execute namespace commands every reboot?

Comment: Namespaces are generally set up in conjunction with some specific service, and normally that service sets up the necessary namespaces itself. The ancient network scripts that you're using certainly have no support for them at all, and even systemd-networkd has only the most minimal support in its most recent versions.